# Xcode says "Expected unqualified -id"

Tags: c++

```
#include "odeint.cpp"
#define main
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main(){

    return 0;
}
```

Xcode keeps on throwing an error "expected unqualified -id" at the ')' after int main. The odeint.cpp is a file from the Numerical Recipes code, and I added the headers from that collection to User Header Search Paths.

Comment: Just remove `#define main`.

Comment: I gotta ask, where'd that `#define main` idea come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#define main` is making your program look like:

```
int () {
  return 0;
}
```

to the compiler, which, as you can see, is wrong.  Remove that line.